How to open Audit Process Creation by coding?
enter image description here
Local Group Policy Editor->Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security settings->Advanced Audit Policy Configuration->System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object->Detailed Tracking->Autid Process Creation
How to set these options to "Success and Failure"?
It is recommended to use python/c/C++ to temporarily turn on the above Settings for the lifetime of the program via the cmd/Registry/Groups Policy.

See here for how to format images: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images . Also please provide some code you've tried so far or resources you find. Stackoverflow is best used when you go when you've tried something out and then get stuck rather than looking for where to start, unless there really is nothing you can find.
